# Iterate through 3 different sliders for RGB in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, slider

I want to make my code more compact. At the moment I have 3 different sliders. One for red, one for green and one for blue colours. I want to make my code more compact, and less hard coded to iterate through these sliders, with a loop.

```
var selection;

$(".slider").slider({
    min: 0, 
    max: 255,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        selection = $(this).slider( "value" );

        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        if(id == 'slider-1'){
            RedBG = selection;
        }

        if(id == 'slider-2'){
            GreenBG = selection;
        }

        if(id == 'slider-3'){
            BlueBG = selection;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why? The code you've got is clear and to the point. I doubt you would make it easier to understand by making it more compact.

Comment: Yes true, I need It for an assignment :-)

Comment: Then, if this is for an assignment i suggest doing the assignment your self. Otherwise you wont learn (whatever they want to teach with this assignment).

Comment: Yes, I tried to make it work, but without any luck so far. I don't need the answer, just a point to the right direction.

Comment: If you've tried something already, please include that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

One way to make this more compact is to store the RGB values as properties of an object, keyed to match the `id` attributes of each slider, something like this:

```js
let $output = $('#output');
let rgb = {
  red: 0,
  green: 0,
  blue: 0
}

$(".slider").slider({
  min: 0,
  max: 255,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    rgb[this.id] = $(this).slider("value");
    $output.text(JSON.stringify(rgb)); // for demo purposes only
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<div class="slider" id="red"></div>
<div class="slider" id="green"></div>
<div class="slider" id="blue"></div>

<div id="output"></div>
```

When necessary you can access the values through the `rgb` object, eg. `rgb.red`